# PHP datetime comparison is not woking normally

Tags: php

Although my question seems can be found the solution on the internet easily. But I've already tried but it's not working.

I've already followed https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php **Example #2 DateTime object comparison**

or another solution like https://thevaluable.dev/php-datetime-create-compare-format/ **Comparing DateTime Objects**

But it is still not working.

Here is my code,

```
$end_time = new DateTime('2020-04-05 23:59:00');
$now = new DateTime('now');
if( $now > $end_time ){
    echo 'expired!';
}
```

It throws the error

> *Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string.*

Edited
 I'm using PHP 7.1.23

Comment: No it doesn't https://3v4l.org/pnqV5

Comment: Maybe you should tell us something about the versions of things specially PHP that you are running

Comment: @RiggsFolly PHP 7.1.23 thanks

Comment: Well that does not explain it :(

Comment: Your code should work. [phpsandbox link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4164a8271870426ac30648eff58c54552f98ffe5). What DateTime class are you using?

Comment: @bravemaster Thats the builtin class DateTime

Comment: @RiggsFolly What I tried to say is that he may be using different DateTime class (maybe in other namespace). As both of us confirmed in sandbox, this snippet should work.

Comment: @HikaruShindo er, it's your question -- you can delete it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem. First you have to convert them into Strings then you can use them. I have changed the input date just to show you the result of if condition.

Select your City for time zone First

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
```

Your Inputs

```
    $input_time = new DateTime('2020-04-01 23:59:00');

    $now = new DateTime('now');
```

Convert them to string

```
    $input_time = $input_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $now = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The result

```
  if( $now > $input_time )
  {
      echo 'expired!'. '<br>'; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be an actual DateTime object, you could use times instead, which will then compare the same as an integer would.

Eg

```
$end_time = strtotime('2020-04-05 23:59:00');
$now = time();
if( $now > $end_time ) {
    echo 'expired!';
}
```